# Move elements to different place with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have successfully created an XSLT template to copy some elements, changing the names of some elements, from one XML file to another.

I can't figure out, though, how to take elements and move them to a different part of the XML structure.

I want to convert this XML:

```
<Hosts>
    <Clusters>
        <Cluster>
            <Nodes>
                <WindowsHost/>
            </Nodes>
        </Cluster>
    </Clusters>
</Hosts>
```

to:

```
<Hosts>
    <WindowsHosts>
        <WindowsHost/>
    </WindowsHosts>
</Hosts>
```

My current working XSLT contains:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

...and then repeating templates like:

```
<xsl:template match="/Hosts/Clusters/Cluster/Nodes/WindowsHost">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Hosts/Clusters/Cluster/Nodes/WindowsHost/SomeElement">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and so on.  Each element to be copied has its own template, since not all elements are copied and some element names are changed.  But I have only succeeded in changing the element name, not the complete XPath.

Any help would be appreciated.

Paul

---

Your response is much appreciated.  But I think my example was too simple, in an attempt to be clear.

My existing XSLT has a template for every element needed to be copied from one XML to the other, so there are lots of templates (almost 1000) and the beginning of the XSLT file makes sure nothing happens to any element by default.  Long story short, I tried the techniques in your answer with no success, probably because the situation is not exactly as I showed you.

There are three scenarios for elements being copied:

1. Copy as is
2. Copy but change the element name
3. Copy to a different location in the schema

The existing XSLT file works with both #1 and #2. It's #3 I can't get to work. Here is more of the XSLT file

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/SAN/ClientProfile">
<!-- copy element as is (working) -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/SAN/ClientProfile/Name">
<!-- copy element but change its name (working) -->
    <CompanyName>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </CompanyName>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/SAN/EQLHosts/WindowsClusters/Cluster/ClusterNodes/WindowsHost">
<!-- copy to different part of schema (not working) -->
    <WindowsHost>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </WindowsHost>
</xsl:template>
```

So, I want to change `/SAN/EQLHosts/WindowsClusters/Cluster/ClusterNodes/WindowsHost` to `/SAN/EQLHosts/WindowsHosts/WindowsHost`.  All children of this element would be handled in the same way as the elements that are already being copied.

I hope my clarifications are clear.  Please let me know if this information changes your answer or whether I am just being dense.

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're really moving anything; just ignoring some elements and adding a new `WindowsHosts` element. Try having a single [indentity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and changing what your `xsl:apply-templates` selects from the `/*` template.

If you still need to rename other elements, just add a new template that matches that element specifically. The identity transform will copy existing elements without modifying them so you won't have to have a template for every element.

Example:

**XML Input**

```
<Hosts>
    <Clusters>
        <Cluster>
            <Nodes>
                <WindowsHost/>
            </Nodes>
        </Cluster>
    </Clusters>
</Hosts>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <WindowsHosts>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Clusters/Cluster/Nodes/WindowsHost"/>
            </WindowsHosts>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Hosts>
   <WindowsHosts>
      <WindowsHost/>
   </WindowsHosts>
</Hosts>
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's an example that includes a rename. It produces the same output using the input above...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!--Start your select at the first element you need to output and/or modify.-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Clusters/Cluster"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Example rename-->
    <xsl:template match="Cluster">
        <WindowsHosts>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Nodes/WindowsHost"/>
        </WindowsHosts>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**EDIT #2**

> So, I want to change
>   `/SAN/EQLHosts/WindowsClusters/Cluster/ClusterNodes/WindowsHost` to
>   `/SAN/EQLHosts/WindowsHosts/WindowsHost`. All children of this element
>   would be handled in the same way as the elements that are already
>   being copied.

In this case, you want to select `WindowsHost` from `EQLHosts`...

```
<xsl:template match="EQLHosts">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <WindowsHosts>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="WindowsClusters/Cluster/ClusterNodes/WindowsHost"/>
        </WindowsHosts>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If there are other children in `EQLHosts` you need to output, you can add that to the first `xsl:apply-templates`. Something like:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*[not(name()='WindowsClusters')]"/>
```

Comment: Your response is much appreciated.  I have added additional information to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Since combining Daniel's answers with my existing XSLT file wasn't working, I created a separate XSLT file to just move those elements to the new place in the XML structure.

This file looks like...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EQLHosts">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <WindowsHosts>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="WindowsClusters/Cluster/ClusterNodes/WindowsHost"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="WindowsClusters/Cluster/VirtualMachines/WindowsHost"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="WindowsHosts/WindowsHost"/>
        </WindowsHosts>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...which works perfectly.  This XSLT file **includes** all elements, while moving some.

My existing XSLT file **excludes** all elements, and only copies those elements specified.  Therefore, I think it's not a bad idea to have two XSLT files, one run right after the other.

Unless there's a way to combine them, I'll keep them as two.